# Linked list recursive reverse

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I was looking at the code below from stanford library:

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
       return;  

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref;
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;  

    /* put the first element on the end of the list */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first; 

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;         

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;
}
```

What I don't understand is in the last recursive step for e.g if list is 1-2-3-4 Now for the last recursive step first will be 1 and rest will be 2. So if you set *head_ref = rest .. that makes the head of the list 2 ?? Can someone please explain how after reversing the head of the list becomes 4 ??

Answer (score 21):

Draw out a stack trace...

```
Intial - {1,2,3,4}
Head - 1
Rest = 2,3,4
Recurse(2,3,4)
Head = 2
Rest = 3,4
Recurse(3,4)
Head = 3 
Rest = 4
Recurse (4)
Head = 4
Rest = null //Base Case Reached!! Unwind.

So now we pick up 
Recurse(3,4)
Head = 3 
Rest = 4
// Return picks up here
first->next->next  = first; 
so list is:
3,4,3
// set head to null,
null ,4,3,
//Off with his head!
4,3
Return

Now we're here
Recurse(2,3,4)
Head = 2
Rest = 3,4
Previous return leaves state as:
Head = 2  //But Head -> next is still 3! -- We haven't changed that yet..
Rest = 4,3  
Head->next is 3, 
Head->next->next = 2 makes the list (actually a tree now)
4->3->2
   ^
   |
   2
And chop off the head leaving
4->3->2
and return.

Similarly, do the last step which will leave
4->3->2->1
      ^
      |
      1
and chop off the head, which removes the one.
```

Comment: @chris:  
 *head_ref = rest; I don't understand it..please help me to overcome this

Comment: head_ref is a reference to the first node in the (sub) list at the current level of recursion.  Rest refers to the first node in the remainder of the list. So setting head_ref to rest has the effect of chopping off the old head.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Please tell how does rest retain its value as 4(i.e the last element of the actual list) after the backtracking of the recursion? Is it because we are passing the address of rest in the function call? Is it matched by the same name of the variable?

Answer (score 19):

Consider the list:

```
   1  ->  2  ->  3  ->  4 -> NULL
   ^      ^
   |      |
 first   rest
```

Where `first` points to the first node and rest points to the node next to `first`.

Since the list is not empty and list does not contain one node we make recursive call to `reverse` to reverse the list pointed to by `rest`. This is how the list looks after reversing the rest of the list:

```
   1  ->  2  <-  3  <-  4
   ^      |             ^
   |     NULL           |
 first                 rest
```

As seen `rest` now points to the reversed list which has `4` at the beginning and `2` at the end of list. The next pointer of node `2` is `NULL`.

Now we need to append the first node to the end of the reversed-rest list. To append anything to the end of the list we need to have access to the last node of the list. In this case we need to have access to the last node of the reversed-rest list. Look at the diagram, `first -> next` points to the last node reversed-rest list. Therefore `first -> next -> next` will be next pointer of the last node of the reversed-rest list. Now we need to make it point to `first` so we do:

```
first -> next -> next = first;
```

After this step the list looks like:

```
   1  <-  2  <-  3  <-  4
   ^  ->                ^
   |                    |
 first                 rest
```

Now the `next` field of the last node of the list must be `NULL`. But it is not the case now. The `next` field of the last node ( node `1`) is pointing to the node before it ( node `2`). To fix this we do:

```
first -> next = NULL;
```

After this the list looks like:

```
NULL <- 1  <-  2  <-  3  <-  4
        ^                    ^
        |                    |
      first                 rest
```

As seen the list is now correctly reversed with `rest` pointing to the head of the reversed list.

We need to return the new head pointer so the that changes are reflected in the calling function. But this is a `void` function and `head` is passed as double pointer so changing the value of `*head` will make the calling function see the changed head:

```
*head = rest;
```

Answer (score 7):

The rest isn’t `2`, it’s `2 -> 3 -> 4`, which gets reversed recursively. **After that** we set `*head_ref` to `rest`, which is now (recursively reversed!) `4 -> 3 -> 2`.

The important point here is that although both `first` and `rest` have the same type, i.e. `node*`, they are conceptually fundamentally different: `first` points to *one single* element, while `rest` points to a *linked list* of elements. This linked list is reversed recursively before it gets assigned to `*head_ref`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a recursive method for reversing a linked list in ruby.  Here it is:

```
def reverse!( node_1 = @head, node_2 = @head.link )
    unless node_2.link 
        node_2.link = node_1
        @head = node_2
        return node_1
    else 
        return_node = reverse!(node_1.link, node_2.link)
        return_node.link = node_1
        node_1.link = nil
        return node_1
    end
    return self
end
```