# How can I get this recursive linked list reverse work?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I tried to write a recursive linked list reverse function and my head is spinning.
Can someone please tell me how can I mend the function?

```
node* recursiveReverse(node* h, node* prev)
{
    node* current = h; //Point to current node
    node* successor = h->next; //Points to next node

    if(successor == NULL)
        return prev;

    successor->next = recursiveReverse(successor,current);
    h->next = NULL;
    return successor;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list recursive reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434411/linked-list-recursive-reverse)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(successor = NULL) // <---
    return prev;
```

Should be `==` here. (`=` is assignment, `==` is compare for equality).

It is a common problem and most compilers should have issued a warning for this. If you haven't turned on warnings (add the `-Wall` flag if you're using gcc or clang), please do so.

Comment: Corrected that flaw. But, how to fix this recursion?

Answer (score 1):

You should also try to write the constants first to avoid such problems. 
For instance: If you write

```
if ( NULL == successor )
   return prev;
```

and you now forget to write two "=", the compiler throws an error because you can't assign NULL a value.