# Recursive Linked List Reversal Function in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse

My List is implemented via these two structs.  The first contains the items in the list while the second contains the list itself.

```
typedef Employee Item;

typedef struct ListNodeTag {
    Item item;
    struct ListNodeTag *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    ListNode *first;
} List;
```

I am trying to use the following recursive function to reverse the contents of the list however, I am getting a segmentation fault once there is more than one item in the list.

```
void Reverse(List *L){
  ListNode *q,*p;

  q = L->first;
  p = q->next;

  if(p == NULL)
    return;

  Reverse(L);

  q->next->next = q;
  q->next = NULL;}
```

I believe that the issue lies in the fact that instead of passing a member of the list as a function argument I am passing a pointer to the list itself.  How would I change this code to let it work without passing a different argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list recursive reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434411/linked-list-recursive-reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass another parameter to the function to advance the recursive function to the end of the list. This can be done like this-

```
void Reverse(ListNode *f, List *l){
    if(l->first == NULL)
        return;

    //Last node reached
    if(f->next==NULL){
        l->first->next = NULL;
        l->first = f;
        return;
    }
    ListNode *p,*q;
    p = f;
    q = f->next;

    Reverse(f->next,l);

    q->next = p;
}
```

Though this function works, it takes a lot of memory, so I'd recommend an iterative approach, like this one-

```
void Reverse(List *l){
    ListNode *f = l->first;
    ListNode *fn,*fnn;

    if(f==NULL)
        return;
    fn = f->next;
    if(fn==NULL)
        return;
    fnn = fn->next;

    while(fnn!=NULL){
        fn->next = f;
        f = fn;
        fn = fnn;
        fnn = fnn->next;
    }
    fn->next = f;
    l->first->next = NULL;
    l->first = fn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to initialise all your next pointers to NULL as you append items to the list?

Also, as I read it, the function won't actually recurse as you're always passing L. In other words, after the first call, how does the function know to go one further step down the list?