# recursive lnkedlist reverse implementation

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

```
//this is code...

void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
        return;  

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref; 
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL){
        return;  
    }

    /* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    printf("\nbefore:%u,%d,%u,%d,%u,%d",*head_ref,               (*head_ref)->data,first,first->data,rest,rest->data);
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    printf("\nafter:%u,%d,%u,%d,%u,%d",*head_ref,(*head_ref)->data,first,first->data,rest,rest->data);
    first->next->next  = first; 

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;         

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;      ///here is my doubt       
}
```

doubt: how this line affect the stack content in the way shown in output

output:

original : 10->12->14->16->18->20->22->

stack content:
before:159592472,10,159592472,10,159592456,12
before:159592456,12,159592456,12,159592488,14
before:159592488,14,159592488,14,159592504,16
before:159592504,16,159592504,16,159592520,18
before:159592520,18,159592520,18,159592536,20
before:159592536,20,159592536,20,159592552,22
recursion reaches bottom
after:159592536,20,159592536,20,159592552,22  //why are 22 printed for each stack when dereferencing rest

after:159592520,18,159592520,18,159592552,22
after:159592504,16,159592504,16,159592552,22
after:159592488,14,159592488,14,159592552,22
after:159592456,12,159592456,12,159592552,22
after:159592472,10,159592472,10,159592552,22
reversed : 22->20->18->16->14->12->10

thanks if you dont understand my question please comment

Comment: If you don't change `*head_ref`, then it would still be pointing at the original first node, which is now the last node.

Comment: such a question is already there  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434411/linked-list-recursive-reverse?rq=1)  but my doubt is why is rest always point to memory containing 22 when it was different(22,20,18,16,14,12) when stack was being filled

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i understand that but if we remove that statement stack content for rest is normal but with this statement stack content of rest changes to 22(last node) at all levels of recursion...i could not get hold of this behaviour...........i mean we are not assigning anything to rest then how does it point to last element

Comment: It is the head_ref that is being assigend, you're passing an & node *l, when you call recursive_reverse.  So you go down to the tail of the list, then on way back, you are at each stage reversing the links.  Then setting the head of the reversed list to the end of the list.