# Linkedlist recursive reverse in c

Tags: c, recursion

The question has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434411/linked-list-recursive-reverse)

Say we don't use the two pointers first and last and simply write

```
if(*head_ref->next==NULL)
{
    p=*head->ref;
    return;
}
recursive(&head_ref->next);
p->next-next=p;
p->next=NULL;
```

This doesn't work, I know it shouldn't, but can't understand why.

First, is there any problem if we pass `*head_ref`? It does actually change the head, but as we are in recursion, should it cause any problem? Also what should we pass as argument in recursive calling?

The correct code is below I just tried to implement that in a different way and I know it's wrong

```
struct Node *head;// Declared Global
void Reverse(struct Node *p)
{
    if(p->next==NULL)
    {
        head=p;
        return;
    }
    Reverse(p->next);
    p->next->next=p;
    p->next=NULL:
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code (see edit)

Comment: With `struct Node *head;`, `*head_ref->next` is wrong.

Comment: @crashmstr I know its' wrong but why? It gives an error request for member next in something that's not a structure or union

Comment: It seems that returning up through your recursion, the `p->next=NULL` assignment is smashing the next reference that you'll need further up. Try taking that statement out.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError
See my comment above i listed one of the errors.
Say the list is 1->2->3->4
Now after we do 4->3 we need to assign 3 to NULL, that is the reason we do p->next=NULL if i don't include that line how would i assign it to NULL

Comment: @Stack `struct Node *head;` declares `head` as a pointer to a `Node` structure. You access the members with `->` when using a pointer. So `head->next` is how you would access the `next` member of the `Node`. You were *dereferencing* the pointer with the `*`.

Comment: @crashmstr yes that is exactly what i am doing accessing the next ele using head->next but it gives an error.

Comment: @Stack no... `*head->next` is *not* accessing the next element. `head->next` accesses the next element.

Comment: @crashmstr we are passing &head in the recursive fn. from main so *head points to first node and *head->next should point to the next element.

Comment: @Stack then you have a global `head` and a function parameter `head`? You *don't* show that, so I must assume `head` is `struct Node *head` and not `struct Node ** head`.

Comment: @crashmstr It is given in the link you can check it..

Comment: @Stack since there is no `p` in that code and it uses `node` and not `Node`, you should post a *complete* example of what *you* are doing.

Comment: Without a complete example of what youre doing, its going to be very hard for anyone to deduce what is happening. Please include what you are trying to compile that exhibits the issue you are asking about